# Best design to avoid "local variable as default parameter"?

Tags: c++, default-parameters

I'm writing an approximation function taking two different tolerance values as parameters:

```
bool Approximate(vector<PointC*>* pOutput, LineC input, double horizontalTolerance, double verticalTolerance)
```

I want the function to set verticalTolerance = horizontalTolerance if verticalTolerance is not set. So, I want to accomplish something like:

```
bool Approximate(vector<PointC*>* pOutput, LineC input, double horizontalTolerance, double verticalTolerance=horizontalTolerance)
```

I know that this is not possible because [local variables are not allowed as default parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50w8cey5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). So my question is, what is the best way to design this function?

The options I thought of are:

1. Don't use a default parameter and make the user set both tolerances explicitly.
2. Set default value of verticalTolerance to a negative value and reset to horizontalTolerance if negative:

   ```
   bool Approximate(vector<PointC*>* pOutput, LineC input, double horizontalTolerance, double verticalTolerance=-1)
   {
       if (verticalTolerance < 0)
       {
           verticalTolerance = horizontalTolerance;
       }
       // Rest of function
   }
   ```

In my oppinion, point one is not a solution but a bypass, and point two cannot be the simplest solution.

Comment: Maybe use function overloading

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use overloading:

```
bool Approximate(vector<PointC*>* pOutput, LineC input, 
                     double horizontalTolerance, double verticalTolerance)
{
//whatever
}

bool Approximate(vector<PointC*>* pOutput, LineC input, 
                     double tolerance)
{
   return Approximate(pOutput, input, tolerance, tolerance);
}
```

This mimics perfectly what you want to achieve.

Comment: +1, but I would nitpickingly name the single tolerance parameter "tolerance", sinced it's not just horizontal.

Comment: I guess that's the most elegant solution so far. Thx!